# Get list of google sheets owned by service account

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gcloud

I created a several spreadsheets owned by gcloud service account by python script.
Is there any way to get list of this spreadsheets owned by this service account?
I don't see any matching method here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've looked into wrong API scope.
Here what I wanted: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#list